# How to correctly alias this git line-counting command in gitconfig?

Tags: windows, bash, git, config, alias

I found this command on Stack Overflow to count the LOC contributions of each user to a repo:

```
git log --no-merges --pretty=format:%an --numstat | awk '/./ && !author { author = $0; next } author { ins[author] += $1; del[author] += $2 } /^$/ { author = ""; next } END { for (a in ins) { printf "%10d %10d %10d %s\n", ins[a] - del[a], ins[a], del[a], a } }' | sort -rn
```

However, when I try to alias this as a command in my .gitconfig, I get all kinds of errors. I have no clue how to correctly escape it so that it runs properly in my bash when I call "git count-lines". I've made multiple attempts based on the other questions on StackOverflow describing git aliasing, but I keep getting different issues.

I've tried a bunch of stuff so far in my gitconfig. This one gives me the fewest errors:

```
[alias]
    count-lines = "!f() { git log --no-merges --pretty=format:%an --numstat | awk '/./ && !author { author = $0; next } author { ins[author] += $1; del[author] += $2 } /^$/ { author = \"\"; next } END { for (a in ins) { printf \"%10d %10d %10d %s\n\", ins[a] - del[a], ins[a], del[a], a } }' | sort -rn; }; f"
```

This is the error that the above gives:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: /./ && ... printf "%10d %10d %10d %s
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ unterminated string  
awk: cmd. line:1: /./ && ... printf "%10d %10d %10d %s 
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
```

(From what I understand, I'm on a windows 7 computer so I need to use quotes around the entire command)

Comment: Just to rule out param substitution problems from your shell : can you see what `git echo aa bb cc` gives, with the following alias : `echo = "!f() { echo '$1 $2 $3'; }; f"` ?

Comment: On my PC (bash / linux), I see  `$1 $2 $3` (not `aa bb cc`)

Comment: @LeGEC I got `$1 $2 $3` as well

Comment: Your alias looks correct. What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: @torek I posted the error in the question. I just figured out the issue though, which is that I need to escape the newline character as well in the printf statement. Otherwise the command gets an actual newline and the string is incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out the problem after an hour and a half of debugging and fiddling around: I need to escape the backslash in the new line character that's in the printf statement.

```
broken: count-lines = "!f() { git log --no-merges --pretty=format:%an --numstat | awk '/./ && !author { author = $0; next } author { ins[author] += $1; del[author] += $2 } /^$/ { author = \"\"; next } END { for (a in ins) { printf \"%10d %10d %10d %s\n\", ins[a] - del[a], ins[a], del[a], a } }' | sort -rn; }; f"
fixed:  count-lines = "!f() { git log --no-merges --pretty=format:%an --numstat | awk '/./ && !author { author = $0; next } author { ins[author] += $1; del[author] += $2 } /^$/ { author = \"\"; next } END { for (a in ins) { printf \"%10d %10d %10d %s\\n\", ins[a] - del[a], ins[a], del[a], a } }' | sort -rn; }; f"
```

---

Edit: Adding final script on request (the below is the entire contents of my `~/.gitconfig` file):

```
[user]
    name = Sam Smith
    email = sam.smith@gmail.com
[alias]
    count-lines = "!f() { git log --no-merges --pretty=format:%an --numstat | awk '/./ && !author { author = $0; next } author { ins[author] += $1; del[author] += $2 } /^$/ { author = \"\"; next } END { for (a in ins) { printf \"%10d %10d %10d %s\\n\", ins[a] - del[a], ins[a], del[a], a } }' | sort -rn; }; f"
```

Comment: Hi, can you share your final script?

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev I have edited my answer with the final state of my `.gitconfig` file